# Magento 2.3 Javascript widget get defaultqty

Tags: magento2, javascript

I want to extend a js widget that applies plus minus buttons. Is there a way to get the defaultqty of a product inside the widget?

```
;(function ($, window, document, undefined) {

$.widget("infortis.qtycontrol", {

    options: {
        qtyButtonSelector: '.qty-button'
        , qtyButtonsWrapperSelector: '.qty-buttons-wrapper'
        , errorColor: 'red'
    }

    , inputField: undefined
    , qtyButtons: undefined

    , _create: function()
    {
        this._initPlugin();
    }

    , _initPlugin: function()
    {
        var _self = this;

        // Get quantity field
        this.inputField = this.element;

        // Insert plus/minus buttons
        this.inputField.after('<div class="qty-buttons-wrapper"></div><div class="qty-button decrease"></div></div>');
        this.inputField.before('<div class="qty-buttons-wrapper"><div class="qty-button increase"></div></div>');

        // Activate plus/minus buttons
        this.qtyButtons = this.inputField.next(this.options.qtyButtonsWrapperSelector).find(this.options.qtyButtonSelector);
        this.qtyButtons.on('click', function() {

            var $button = $(this);
            var oldValue = _self.inputField.val();
            var newVal = 0;

            if (isNaN(oldValue))
            {
                _self.inputField.css('color', _self.options.errorColor);
            }
            else
            {
                if ($button.hasClass('increase'))
                {
                    newVal = _self.qtyAdd(parseFloat(oldValue), 1, 4);
                    _self.inputField.css('color', '');
                }
                else 
                {
                    var candidateNewValue = _self.qtySubtract(parseFloat(oldValue), 1, 4);
                    if (oldValue > 0 && candidateNewValue > 0) 
                    {
                        newVal = candidateNewValue;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        newVal = 0;
                        _self.inputField.css('color', _self.options.errorColor);
                    }
                }

                _self.inputField.val(newVal);
            }

        });

    }

    , qtyAdd: function(a, b, precision)
    {
        var x = Math.pow(10, precision || 2);
        return (Math.round(a * x) + Math.round(b * x)) / x;
    }

    , qtySubtract: function(a, b, precision)
    {
        var x = Math.pow(10, precision || 2);
        return (Math.round(a * x) - Math.round(b * x)) / x;
    }

  }); //end: widget

})(jQuery, window, document);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass Product Default qty as config argument to your custom Js Component as describe below:

Assume you are using a custom module names "Company_MyModule"

**step 1)**

create the layout file **catalog_product_view.xml** under *app/code/Company_MyModule/view/frontend/layout/*

File :  **catalog_product_view.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">            
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Company_MyModule::catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Step 2)**

Create the Template file **addtocart.phtml** under */app/code/Company_MyModule/view/frontend/templates/catalog/product/view/*

File : **addtocart.phtml**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/** @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View */
?>
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $buttonTitle = __('Add to Cart'); ?>
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
<div class="box-tocart">
    <div class="fieldset">
        <?php if ($block->shouldRenderQuantity()): ?>
        <div class="field qty">
            <label class="label" for="qty"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Qty') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control" data-bind="scope: 'qty_change'">
                        <button class="qty-inc" data-bind="click: increaseQty"><i class="icon-up-dir">+</i></button>
                        <input data-bind="value: qty()"
                               type="number"
                               name="qty"
                               id="qty"
                               maxlength="12"
                               value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>"
                               title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty"
                               data-validate="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(json_encode($block->getQuantityValidators())) ?>"
                               />
                        <button data-bind="click: decreaseQty" class="qty-dec"><i class="icon-down-dir">-</button>                                      
                        <!--<div class="qty-changer">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)"  data-bind="click: increaseQty" class="qty-inc"><i class="icon-up-dir">+</i></a>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-bind="click: decreaseQty" class="qty-dec"><i class="icon-down-dir">-</i></a>
                        </div>-->
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="actions">
            <button type="submit"
                    title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $buttonTitle ?>"
                    class="action primary tocart"
                    id="product-addtocart-button">
                <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $buttonTitle ?></span>
            </button>
            <?= $block->getChildHtml('', true) ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#product_addtocart_form": {
            "Magento_Catalog/js/validate-product": {}
        },
        "*": {
           "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
               "components": {
                   "qty_change": {
                       "component": "Company_MyModule/js/view/product/view/qty_change",
                       "defaultQty": <?php echo $block->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>
                   }
               }
           }
        }

    }
</script>
```

**Step 3)**

Create your custom js file **qty_change.js** under *app/code/Company_MyModule/view/frontend/web/js/view/product/view/*

File : **qty_change.js**

```
define([
   'ko',
   'uiComponent'
], function (ko, Component) {
   'use strict';
   return Component.extend({
       initialize: function () {
           //initialize parent Component
           this._super();
           this.qty = ko.observable(this.defaultQty);
       },
       decreaseQty: function() {
           var newQty = this.qty() - 1;
           if (newQty < 1) 
           {
               newQty = 1;
           }           
           this.qty(newQty);
       },
       increaseQty: function() {
           var newQty = this.qty() + 1;          
           this.qty(newQty);
       }
   });
});
```